# Discourse: Is it possible to embed and show <object> svg images?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, discourse

I am woundering if I could be somehow embed the following code and show the image inside a Discourse Post:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://o.smium.org/api/convert/7899/svg/7899-pvp-vexor.svg"><a href="https://o.smium.org/loadout/7899">View PVP Vexor on Osmium</a></object>
```

I am planning a section with discussion about those inGame ship fittings, and it would be beautiful if they could be directly embedded without any hustle of work covertig those svg´s into jpgs or similar. When using the editor and post object tag like above, its been coberted into a link. Same when posting the .svg link itself.

Thanks for help,
Daniel

Comment: can you ask on meta you probably do not want to whitelist an object tag, cause you can introduce a big bunch of security exploits.

Comment: hi @SamSaffron, i did post it first on meta without a reaction: [link](https://meta.discourse.org/t/is-it-possible-to-embed-and-show-object/84159)